# Azure Mobile Service and Concurrency on database actions?

Tags: sql-server, database, concurrency, azure-mobile-services

I recently read into Azure Tables and I the system has an implemented E-tag check for checking concurrent actions. I assume that for Azure Mobile Service, each of the insert and update methods etc. are atomic, however, I have been hard pressed to find any real information on concurrent data access. Should I want such to be implemented, is it up to me to implement it or does Azure Mobile Service implement some kind of concurrency handling system.

A basic use case I am looking into is the most basic

1. User 1 gets object A
2. User 2 gets object A
3. User 2 saves object A
4. User 1 saves object A -> This should result in a fault

Is it up to me to implement this? And how should I go about it? My first instinct would be to manually add an E-tag field for the object that is checked by a server-side script. Is there a better approach?

Comment: did you get any solution for this problem? I am also searching for the same.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that because WAMS is using SQL tables that it uses Optimistic Locking. So, I think the E-Tag is the way to go.

The following articles should shed some light on SQL for Azure:

[Windows Azure Storage and Concurrent Access](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/02/23/windows-azure-storage-and-concurrent-access.aspx)

[Best Practices for the Design of Large-Scale Services on Windows Azure Cloud Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj717232.aspx)

[How to get most out of Windows Azure Tables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The links you gave appear to mostly concentrate on the Azure Tables solution (My understanding is that it is a no-SQL solution). I guess my original question was a bit poorly articulated as I am interested in the actual SQL that's used as a default by Azure Mobile Service, instead of the tables that already implement the E-tag check.